# Hiding a div if a value is under 1

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want the application to behave this way so that when I click on "Show Order" if any of the values are 0 or blank, I don't want div id item * x be shown:

```js
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

var toggle = function() {
  for (var i = 0, l = divs.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (divs[i].getAttribute('class') == 'problem')
      if (divs[i].style.display == 'none') divs[i].style.display = '';
      else divs[i].style.display = 'none';
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
    var y = document.getElementById("item1").value;
    if (x < 1) {
      y.style.display === "none"
    } else {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
    }
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect1").value;
    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = x;
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect2").value;
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = x;
  }
}

document.getElementById('Toggle').onclick = toggle;
```

```html
<div class="problem">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
      <form>
        <input type="number" id="mySelect" name="mySelect" autocomplete="off" style="width: 3em;"> Sausage
        <br>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <form>
        <input type="number" id="mySelect1" name="mySelect1" autocomplete="off" style="width: 3em;"> Pancake
        <br>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      <form>
        <input type="number" id="mySelect2" name="mySelect2" autocomplete="off" style="width: 3em;"> Milk
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <p>
        <button type="button" class="button" id="Toggle" onclick="myFunction()">Show Order</button>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div style="display:none;" class="problem">Please show this to the cashier.</div>

    <div style="display:none;" class="problem">
      <h2>Hello, they ordered:</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="item1" style="display:none;" class="problem">
      <h2><span style="font-size: xx-large; color: green;" id="demo"></span>x&nbsp;Sausage(s)</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="item2" style="display:none;" class="problem">
      <h2><span style="font-size: xx-large; color: green;" id="demo1"></span>x&nbsp;Pancake(s)</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="item3" style="display:none;" class="problem">
      <h2><span style="font-size: xx-large; color: green;" id="demo2"></span>x&nbsp;Cup of Milk(s)</h2>
    </div>
    <div style="display:none;" class="problem">
      <h2>Thank you</h2>
    </div>

    <div style="display:none;" class="problem">Please refresh your browser to restart your order</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have added my full code from JSFiddle here.

Comment: Post the code in the question. Use stackoverflow snipplets.

Comment: And provide a properly detailed problem description. See [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Check this simpler approach

- Give a display class to div to be div to be toggled
- Check for any input values to be `>= 1`

**Demo**

```js
var toggle = function() {
  var x1 = Number(document.getElementById("mySelect").value);
  var x2 = Number(document.getElementById("mySelect1").value);
  var x3 = Number(document.getElementById("mySelect2").value);
  document.querySelectorAll(".display .problem").forEach(function(el) {
    el.style.display = x1 >= 1 || x2 >= 1 || x3 >= 1 ? "block" : "none";
  });
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (x1 || 0);
  document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = (x2 || 0);
  document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = (x3 || 0);
}

document.getElementById('Toggle').onclick = toggle;
```

```html
<div class="problem">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
      <form>
        <input type="number" id="mySelect" name="mySelect" autocomplete="off" style="width: 3em;"> Sausage
        <br>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <form>
        <input type="number" id="mySelect1" name="mySelect1" autocomplete="off" style="width: 3em;"> Pancake
        <br>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      <form>
        <input type="number" id="mySelect2" name="mySelect2" autocomplete="off" style="width: 3em;"> Milk
      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="col-4">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <p>
        <button type="button" class="button" id="Toggle" onclick="myFunction()">Show Order</button>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="row display">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div style="display:none;" class="problem">Please show this to the cashier.</div>

    <div style="display:none;" class="problem">
      <h2>Hello, they ordered:</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="item1" style="display:none;" class="problem">
      <h2><span style="font-size: xx-large; color: green;" id="demo"></span>x&nbsp;Sausage(s)</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="item2" style="display:none;" class="problem">
      <h2><span style="font-size: xx-large; color: green;" id="demo1"></span>x&nbsp;Pancake(s)</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="item3" style="display:none;" class="problem">
      <h2><span style="font-size: xx-large; color: green;" id="demo2"></span>x&nbsp;Cup of Milk(s)</h2>
    </div>
    <div style="display:none;" class="problem">
      <h2>Thank you</h2>
    </div>

    <div style="display:none;" class="problem">Please refresh your browser to restart your order</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through all the divs with `class="problem"` and check their `input`'s values. If there's nothing, then don't show it. If it isn't empty, show it.

You can achieve this with `var allDivs = querySelectorAll('.problem input');` to get the inputs in the divs (since we know they have `class="problem"`), and then loop through that and use an if to check `allDivs[i].value`.

I didn't want to give the code directly, so hopefully this helps answer your question!

Answer (score -1):

Here you are :

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/1znqk6us/1/`
```

I've removed onlick event on button because you don't use this, and for loop.